# Sandbox Record Access Insufficient Priviledges

Tags: administration, security, sharing, system

Are you able to advise why the System Administrator profile cannot access a record owned by the member of a queue it is not a member of even when it is has view/modify ALL on the Object AND other records owned by the same queue open successfully?

This is a recently populated Partial Copy Sandbox with a change set not yet in production.  In production if I try and access the records it works every time.

I have been struggling with and am beginning to think it's related to the sampling of data during the Sandbox refresh... I thought CRUD permissions of an object are the base level of access..

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce administrator has all the privileges that are required to modify any record, you must check if there are any permission sets defined to block your access and try to remove them. 
Let me know if this worked